# Section/Subsection naming in Greek

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, babel, greek

I would like to replace the words "Secon" and "SubSecon" with something in Greek.
Also i would like to have the Table of contents showing everything correctly.
Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Secon \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{SubSecon \arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{First subsection}\label{subsec:first}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:second}.
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{subsec:second}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:first}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Greek as normal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Ενότητα} \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Υποδιαίρεση} \arabic{subsection}}
% I trust Google translate :))
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{First subsection}\label{subsec:first}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:second}.
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{subsec:second}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:first}.
\end{document}
```

However, the output is extremely messy.

[image]

You should use `titlesec` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
    {\foreignlanguage{greek}{Ενότητα} \thesection\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
    {\foreignlanguage{greek}{Υποδιαίρεση} \thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{}
% I trust Google translate :))
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{First subsection}\label{subsec:first}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:second}.
\subsection{Second subsection}\label{subsec:second}
Some text from subsection \ref{subsec:first}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your document is wholly in Greek, consider setting `babel` so that Greek is the global language.